# SQL Server add row numbers without ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, row-number

I have a massive data file (tab delimited). I'm experiencing a data shift- at some point, the date field becomes populated with non-date values (the words from the description field to the left of it). 
As you can imagine, I can't just scroll through the text file, or plop it into excel to dig around- I need to know where to look.

I am trying to add row numbers to the imported table, so that I can identify the row where the data shift occurs. 
So, I am wondering if there is a way to insert row numbers without having to order by anything (i.e. essentially number the rows of the original data file).

Using

> ROW_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (___))

I'm not sure how to accomplish what I'm trying to do, because I can't order on anything- it needs to be numbered exactly as it was imported.

Comment: Hint : `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT 1`.

Comment: Note that without a sensible `ORDER BY`, there is no guaranteed order in SQL. E.g. if the server happens to experience a Page Split or any other event that rearranges data 'under the hood', then the order of returned rows will also change. And this may have happened many times before you even run your first query.

Comment: To elaborate on the `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT 1` which will not produce repeated results, you'll want to read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: Is it shifting due to a delimiter (tab) in a text column? Hopefully that column is quote wrapped or it is going to be tough to handle. If you are trying to find this line, import entire row into 1 col and then do len(col) - len(replace(col,char(9),""))

Comment: If you could open it in excel, you could add a column and have excel number it for you (just do the first 2-3 rows and then have excel do the rest) - then you will have the exact row order.

Comment: After the fact, no.  As others have mentioned there is no guaranteed order in SQL.  You would have to as part of your import add the line/row number at time of import.   Which there are several ways of accomplishing that.   But that would mean you would have to import again.

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet is to import it into a staging table with an IDENTITY column added to it.